Does moving the idler in a wheel and disk CVT conserve energy or momentum?
Consider the wheel and disk CVTs (continuous variable transmissions) below. Configuration A comprises a CVT disk coupled to the "system under control" 's', whereby a control wheel 'cw' constructed from a continuous omni-wheel engages with it perpendicularly, translating left and right with minimal resistance (assume no friction in this case), its being coupled to a flywheel 'f'. Let 's' and 'f' have effective moments of inertia $I_s$ and $I_f$, whereby the angular velocities are related by $\omega_f=\frac{r_c}{r_{cw}}\omega_s$; for Configuration B which alters the input and output rotation axes to be parallel, $\omega_f=\frac{-x_{cw}}{d_{cw}+x_{cw}}\omega_s$.

I wish to analyze the dynamics of the momentum transfer from moving the control wheel (i.e. for $\omega_f=\frac{vt+r_{c0}}{r_{cw}}\omega_s$ in Configuration A or $\omega_f=-\frac{vt+x_{cw0}}{d_{cw}+(vt+x_{cw0})}\omega_s$ in Configuration B where $v \neq 0$ and $t >= 0$), whereby I am unclear on whether this system is supposed to conserve rotational kinetic energy or angular momentum. As you will see below, my present attempts lead to only one or the other being conserved.

In conserving momentum (solving for $\omega_s$ in $L_{T0}=I_s\omega_s+I_f\omega_f$), I would find it most odd that the motion of the control wheel without a reaction force beyond the control wheel's own translational inertia would impart work on the system mind incur a vertical asymptote.
In conserving energy (solving for $\omega_s$ in $E_{T0}=\frac{1}{2}(I_s\omega_s^2+I_f\omega_f^2)$), though the predictions of angular velocity and acceleration with respect to time are more sensible, I find it unclear whether we should expect the dynamic changing of the CVT ratio to impart a net change on the system's angular momentum.

To show how I arrived upon these disparities, I have provided https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n8aypfivci and https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wqncpali6t which contain interactive graphs of my equations for Configurations A and B, respectively:

In each, the first folder contains sliders for the parameters with descriptions; the second folder models the system assuming conservation of energy; the third folder models the system assuming conservation of momentum (I admit I may have not properly set up the total angular momentum for orthogonally rotating bodies for Configuration A, but a similar disparity is found with the Configuration B calculations).
One can click on the folder icons to show and hide the curves for conservation of energy and momentum, respectively. The green curve is the total rotational kinetic energy. The blue curve is the total angular momentum (likely incorrect in Configuration A, but likely correct in Configuration B). The orange curve is $\omega_s$. The red curve is $\omega_f$. The purple curve is the angular acceleration $\alpha_s$.


Consider to spell out acronyms.
